# Using Powershell to search a list of devices for files with a certain extension

Tags: powershell

I have a need to search a list of computers I have in a text file for all files with the extension .js which were created between two dates and then export this to a CSV.

I have done a few versions but each one has an issue in some way. My latest version below will only check the local device I am logged into and not any of the ones in the list, it gives an error of:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:2 char:2
+ {Invoke-Command -computername $server
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

The code I am running is below:

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\servers.txt
$report = @()
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
    Invoke-Command -computername $server 
    $info = Get-ChildItem "*.js" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge "05/07/2023" -and $_.CreationTime -le "11/07/2023"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
    $report+=$info
}

$report
$report | Export-Csv -Path "c:\results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I have looked at various code on here and elsewhere but haven't been able to piece together something which is quite right.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke-Command is basically complaining that you haven't given it enough parameter arguments for it to figure out *what you want it to do*.

You need to enclose the code that needs to run remotely in a scriptblock `{...}` and pass it as an argument to `Invoke-Command`:

```
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
    $info = Invoke-Command -computername $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem "*.js" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge "05/07/2023" -and $_.CreationTime -le "11/07/2023"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
    }
    $report+=$info
}
```

Comment: That is great thanks, has resolved the error I was having and is now going through the list great.

Comment: @Wychrit That's great, you're most welcome! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark outlined on the left :)